# Adding different script into header depending on selected language

Tags: javascript, header, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

:)

I'd like to add [this script](https://codeshare.io/5v43p7) into the header of my ps 1.7 installation. I got it working in the themes/theme_name/templates/_partials/head.tpl file but as stated in the title, I can't add different scripts depending on the selected language.

After that, I've tried to add it via static block plug-ins hooked to the header of the website, since they allowed me to add different code for each language. But that didn't quite work. I got it to work once and the code was visibly broken. In the other hook / module combinations, it didn't work at all.

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to create a module, and then save each script in their language configuration.
The easiest way is what you've done ;)

Edit `themes/theme_name/templates/_partials/head.tpl`

```
{if $language.language_code == 'en'}
    //script for EN
{elseif $language.language_code == 'es'}
    //script for ES
....
{/if}
```